# Не работает программа на C#

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте. Совсем недавно начал осваивать C#, до этого писал с PascalABC, ну вы поняли мой уровень. Итак, перейду к самой программе. Её суть заключается в том, чтобы создать прямоугольную матрицу, а если по простому, то массив 20x5 элементов. В каждую ячейку нужно присвоить романизированное значение от 1 до 5 включительно. В конце программы должно быть выведено кол-во элементов равных 5. Вот что я написал:

```
        Random random = new Random();
        const int n = 5;
        const int v = 20;
        int[,] a = new int[v, n];
        int y = 5;
        int x = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= v; i++)
        {
            for (int z = 1; z <= n; z++)
            {
                a[i, z] = random.Next(1 , 6);
                Console.Write(a[i, z] + " ");
                if (a[i, z] == y)
                {
                    x++;
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            Console.WriteLine(x);
            Console.ReadLine();
         }
```

Я не пытался разобраться самостоятельно, но так ничего и не понял. Visual'ka показывает ошибку в строке "a[i, z] = random.Next(1 , 6);". Хотелось бы понять, что я написал не так и увидеть исправленный или переделанный код. Заранее спасибо.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А текст сообщения об ошибке вы сами придумайте, у меня лапки.

Comment: В [tag:c#] индекс у массивов начинается с 1? :)

Comment: С 0, но я же с паскаля к вам пришёл.

Comment: @Tzex: Дело сути не меняет, занимайтесь отладкой перед тем как задавать вопросы.

Comment: Впредь буду внимательнее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Типичная ошибка при работе с массивами, индекс массивов (не пользовательских), начинается с `0`.
Так же почитайте о классе [Random](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.random(v=vs.110).aspx) и его методе [Next](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/2dx6wyd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Random random = new Random();
const int n = 5;
const int v = 20;
int[,] a = new int[v, n];
int y = 5;
int x = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < v; i++)
{
    for (int z = 0; z < n; z++)
    {
        a[i, z] = random.Next(1 , 6);
        Console.Write(a[i, z] + " ");
        if (a[i, z] == y)
        {
            x++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    Console.WriteLine(x);
    Console.ReadLine();
 }
```

---

```
Tests (1 test) [0:01.268] Success
 yami.ui.tests (1 test) [0:01.268] Success
  yami.ui.tests.Services (1 test) [0:01.268] Success
   SettingsModelTest (1 test) [0:01.268] Success
    Test [0:01.268] Success


Трассировка отладки:
5 3 1 5 5 Count: 3
4 2 5 2 2 Count: 4
4 2 1 3 5 Count: 5
4 2 5 4 1 Count: 6
3 1 2 5 5 Count: 8
5 1 4 2 2 Count: 9
3 3 3 1 2 Count: 9
5 2 3 2 5 Count: 11
2 1 1 1 4 Count: 11
2 5 3 5 3 Count: 13
2 4 3 1 3 Count: 13
4 1 1 5 1 Count: 14
4 4 4 5 4 Count: 15
1 4 1 2 1 Count: 15
3 4 4 4 5 Count: 16
3 1 2 2 4 Count: 16
5 3 4 4 5 Count: 18
5 1 2 4 3 Count: 19
5 1 4 1 2 Count: 20
3 3 1 2 3 Count: 20
```

Comment: Спасибо большое.